# Как создать 10 потоков в java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Не получается создать 10 потоков в java.
Вот код создания потоков:

```
ConnectThread connectThread[] = new ConnectThread[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    connectThread[i] = new ConnectThread(login, password, host);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    connectThread[i].start();
}
```

Класс ConnectThread:

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run connect 1");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

В итоге создается от одного до пяти потоков,
но никак не десять.

Пробовал добавлять join - не помогает.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я, может, ошибаюсь, но System.exit() останавливает виртуальную машину. То есть у вас успевает запуститься часть потоков, после чего один из них выходит из приложения через System.exit(). Попробуйте убрать его и посмотреть что получится

Comment: ага получилось

Answer (score -2):

В java таким образом можно создать 10 потоков, можно и 14. 
Попробуйте сменить комп,
но вариант без exit(), конечно, дешевле.